Questions about lemma in a proof of the PNT
Sorry for a bit of preamble for my question but I feel it's necessary to actually ask it. I also don't know how to put certain mathematical notation into text so this is going to be a lot wordier than it needs to be, although this isn't algebra heavy so it should be readable.
The lemma, (which appears in an article from The American Mathematical Monthly entitled Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem) states that if a Laplace transform of a bounded integrable function f(t) from R->C extends to an analytic function g(z) for real(z)>=0, then the integral from 0 to infinity of f(t)dt exists and equals g(0). In short, we can interchange the limit and integral safely under these conditions. While the article doesn't state it I feel it should be necessary to add the condition that g(z) is meromorphic for some region a<real(z)<0, where a is negative. It doesn't matter how small a is as long as it exists and is non-zero. When this lemma is used g(z) happens to meromorphic with poles at the zeroes of the Riemann-zeta function with -1<real(z)<0, where the zeroes are shifted to the left by 1. (So for example a zero of zeta at 1/2+it translates to a pole of g(z) at -1/2+it)
I don't have a problem with most of the proof offered, except for one bit at the start. It uses Cauchy's integral formula to write the g(z) (and some other stuff but the other stuff is entire) as an integral over the following region:
The circle |z|=R for some R, cut vertically by the line Real(z)= -d, for some d>0. Let's call this contour C.
For Cauchy's integral formula to hold the function needs to be analytic within the boundary, and this is were my doubts lie.
Since it includes part of the plane with negative real part, we need to be sure d can be chosen small enough to avoid the zeroes of the zeta function within this region. Part of the proof is letting R grow arbitrarily large, so we need show that d does exist with this in mind. To my eyes, there exists certain distribution of zeroes in which no d exist such that g(z) is analytic in the region bounded by C. For example say g(z) has poles at the reciprocals at every negative integer.
So -1/2,-1/3,-1/4... etc
Note these poles are still isolated as for each pole there exists an e>0 such that the region |z+1/n|<e contains no poles except for z=-1/n, so under my understanding of what it means for a function to be meromorphic g(z) is still meromorphic. But also for any fixed d, there will exist infinity many poles within C, so cauchy's integral formula does not hold. Now this specific distribution of poles is not a problem, since it would imply discontinuity at z=0 as we take a limit from the negative real axis, therefore meaning g(z) is not analytic for all z with Real(z)=0, contradicting our conditions for our theorem.
But what still seems to be a problem is if you spread out these poles or another set of numbers like this by adding some imaginary part, for example, -1/2+15i,-1/3+22i,-1/4-50i... etc. You could spread these out far enough so that discontinuity is not implied or at least I don't see how to prove it is implied, and since in order for this proof to work R needs to be able to tend towards infinity, the size of the imaginary parts isn't that important. Now this isn't necessarily a problem for poles spread out over a non-finite region. (What I mean by non-finite is that for any region of the complex plane with finite area there are finitely many poles within this region.) This is because you could adjust d as R grows to avoid zeroes and you would be fine.
But what I can't resolve (and if you read this far, congratulations you finally got to my question sorry i'm not good a brevity) is if you spread this kind of distribution out over a finite region where the imaginary part is bounded between two values. Under such a region we could not find d "quick enough" to allow R grow arbitrarily large, for much the same reason as why no d existed in my initial example we could never let R grow bigger than the bounds on our imaginary part would allow. At the same time it's not obvious how this contradicts our conditions for this theorem.
I'm a freshman in college and I haven't formally taken a complex analysis class (although I've studied the basics) so if this question is trivial, standard material or otherwise built on a fundamental misunderstanding I apologize for the waste of time. Big Thanks to anyone who can help me resolve this.

Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
